# The dbsecurefile instance parameter value must be set to PẺMITTED

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a problem when I install Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c:

[image: This is my error]

I searched Google then I tried this, but it's still not working. What should I do now?

[image: I try this]

Comment: Fix image previews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the parameter for the relevant pdb, not the cdb. Based on the value for `show pdbs;`, it looks like you ran the `alter system` command for the container database, not the pluggable database.